# Letting Pin select one Category

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, categories

I have problem letting my pin select 1 category, below is what I had attempted.

```
$ rails g model category name:string

$ rails g migration add_category_id_to_event

in /db/migrate/XXXX_add_category_id_to_pin
```

I modified

```
class AddCategoryIdToPin < ActiveRecord::Migration
def self.up
  add_column :pins, :category_id, :integer
 end

def self.down
 remove_column :pin, :category_id
  end
 end


 Rake db:migrate
```

in app/models/pin.rb

```
 class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
 end
```

in app/models/category.rb

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :pins
 end
```

in rails console

```
Category.create( :name => "Course" )
Category.create( :name => "Meeting" )
Category.create( :name => "Conference" )
```

In app/views/pins/_form.html.erb

```
<%= f.select :category_id, category_options %>
```

In pp/views/pins/show.html.erb

```
<p>Category: <%= @pin.category.name %><p>
```

in app/helpers/pins_helper.rb

```
module PinsHelper
 def category_options
    Category.all.map{ |c| [c.name, c.id] }
 end
end
```

But now nothing shows up on my app and I get the below, before all this was working fine. So I don't understand where went wrong? Can Some one help?

NameError in Pins#index

Showing /Users/mattbook/code/dine/app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb where line #17 raised:

undefined local variable or method `new_pin_path' for #<#:0x007f92565413d0>
Extracted source (around line #17):

14:
15:                     
16:                     
17:                             <% if user_signed_in? %>

<%= link_to "拚 +", new_pin_path %>

18:

19:                               個人
20:

Comment: Can you please share your routes for the pins?

Comment: In your migration, you're referring to :pins (plural) when adding your column, and :pin (singular) when removing it.

Comment: @ Bachan, I am sorry, I am really new to rails. When you refer to routes for pins, are you referring to routes.rb?

Comment: @joshua.paling  So should both with singular or plural? So sorry, I am really bad.

Comment: Please write this following code in your console and share the output. CONTROLLER=pins rake routes

Comment: @Bachan Sorry, I am getting this                                                       2.0.0p247 :002 > CONTROLLER=pins rake routes
NameError: undefined local variable or method `routes' for main:Object

Comment: Both should be plural - :pins

Comment: @MatthewW. sorry it was my mistake, just run the code in the terminal. or share your config/routes.rb

Comment: @Joshua.paling Thanks got it fixed, with the singular and plural problem. May I ask how I can set up to display all the pins in a category?

Comment: @MatthewW. you'll need to show us routes.rb

Comment: @Joshua below is routes.rb                   Dine::Application.routes.draw do
get "users/show"

  resources :pins

  devise_for :users
  match 'users/:id' => 'users#show', as: :user

  root :to => 'pins#index'
  get 'about' => 'pages#about'
  get 'weekly' => 'pages#weekly'
  get 'shop' => 'pages#shop'
  get 'service' => 'pages#service'
 get 'privacy' => 'pages#privacy'
  get 'test' => 'pages#test'
  

  match 'contact' => 'contact#new', :as => 'contact', :via => :get
  match 'contact' => 'contact#create', :as => 'contact', :via => :post
end

Comment: Sorry, not sure how I can present it better.

Comment: you can edit your original question, and post it in there. Use 4-space indentation to get it to format correctly.